Does exist an orthogonal matrix $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$ such that $U_1 = U_2 Q$?
Original Problem (Case 1):
Given that $U_1 \Lambda U_1^\top = U_2 \Lambda U_2^\top$, where $U_1, U_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$, $U_1^\top U_1 = U_2^\top U_2 = I_r$ and $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}\big\{I_{r'}, -I_{r - r'}\big\}$, we can find an orthogonal matrix $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$ such that $U_1 = U_2 Q$.

Modified Problem (Case 2):
Given that $U_1 \Lambda U_1^\top = U_2 \Lambda U_2^\top$, where $U_1, U_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$, $U_1^\top U_1 = I_r$ and $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}\big\{I_{r'}, -I_{r - r'}\big\}$$\color{red}{\big(\; U_2^\top U_2 = I_r \text{ is deleted }\big)}$,does there exist an orthogonal matrix $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$ such that $U_1 = U_2 Q$?
I attempt to construct a counterexample to demonstrate that Case 2 does not hold.

Supplement
This problem should not be difficult.I previously neglected certain fundamental properties of real symmetric matrices.
Suppose $L \Lambda L^{\top}$ represents the reduced eigenvalue decomposition of $R$, where $L \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$ and $\text{rank}(L) = r$.
Let $L = \big(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_{r'}, \beta_1, \ldots, \beta_{r - r'}\big)$, which can be expressed as $\text{Span}\big\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_{r'}\big\} \bigoplus \text{Span}\big\{\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_{r - r'}\big\}$. The eigenspaces $V_{\lambda_1} = \text{Span}\big\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_{r'}\big\}$ and $V_{\lambda_2} = \text{Span}\big\{\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_{r - r'}\big\}$ correspond to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2 = -1$, respectively.
By orthonormalizing $V_{\lambda_1}$ and $V_{\lambda_2}$, we obtain $U_1 = \text{Span}\big\{\tilde{\alpha}_1, \ldots, \tilde{\alpha}_{r'}\big\} \bigoplus \text{Span}\big\{\tilde{\beta}_1, \ldots, \tilde{\beta}_{r - r'}\big\}$.
Then $U_1\Lambda U^{\top}_1=R,U_1^{T}U_1=I_r.$ Since $L^{\top}L\ne I_r$,we cannot find an orthogonal matrix $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$ such that $L = U_1 Q$!

Case 1 does not make much sense, for any orthogonal $U_1,U_2$ you can find orthogonal $Q$ with $U_1=U_2Q$

@ Levent
When $ U_1 $ and $ U_2 $ are both $ n \times n $ square matrices, you are correct! However, please note that here $ U_1$ and $U_2$ are $ n \times r$ matrices.eg $U_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1&  0\
0&  1\
0&  0\
\end{pmatrix}, U_2=\begin{pmatrix}
1&  0\
0&  0\
0&  1\
\end{pmatrix}$.

why does it say in red "$\color{red}{\text{delete } U_2^\top U_2 = I_r}$"?  If $U_1 = U_2Q$ then $I_r = Q^T (U_2^TU_2)Q \implies I_r =Q I_r Q^{-1}= U_2^TU_2$ so this is obviously necessary

@user8675309 Perhaps the logical structure of Case 2 has not been fully clarified: Given $U_1 \Lambda U_1^\top = U_2 \Lambda U_2^\top$, where $U_1, U_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$, $U_1^\top U_1 = I_r$, and $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(I_{r'}, -I_{r - r'}) \overset{\text{?}}{\Longrightarrow}$  the existence of an orthogonal matrix $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$ such that $U_1 = U_2 Q$.

My point is Case 2 reduces to Case 1 almost immediately.  Also to show something has been deleted people would typically note that in past tense & in parenthesis or use strikethrough notation so I found the red text puzzling for a while.

It should be easy to construct a counterexample. E.g. when $\Lambda=\pmatrix{1\\ &-1},U_1=I_2$ and $U_2=\pmatrix{\sqrt{2} & 1\\ 1 & \sqrt{2}}$, we have $U_i\Lambda U_i^T=\Lambda$ for each $i$. However, as $U_2$ is not orthogonal, $Q=U_2^{-1}U_1=U_2^{-1}$ is also not orthogonal.
